# Protect server IP root with user and password

Tags: php, linux, authentication, phpmyadmin, debian

I'm running this control panel in Debian server: https://github.com/OpenGamePanel/OGP-Website/wiki

After the installation, I just have to access to Panel using my server IP.

But I want to protect it with user-password before accessing the site (to prevent inspect tools, info, or other tools) as I did with PHPMyAdmin URL:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdLKT.png

Added this: AllowOverride All

Here: sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

And this: AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Here: sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess

But not sure how to do the same for this panel to protect the / URL

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just create (or edit the existing) `.htaccess` file in the document root of your control panel with these contents

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

the user/password will be the same as for your phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer but in AuthUserFile I see there's something pointing to PHPMyAdmin but this control panel uses the file? How do I know that I'm editing or creating the file in the correct path? Thanks!